# Does changing major if you’re not passionate about a good idea or should I accept what I have and live with it?

Tags: community-college

I’m a 26 yo with a BA in English. While studying and even the 3 years after I never felt EL fits me the best but still finished it with the hope of studying again the major I like (and trust me it was a hard decision to take as doing another 4 years is unacceptable here especially people here (including my family) thinks of getting job and live with it to the end. Now I'm studying CS. but felt like… What the hell am I doing with my life? Students with me are 8-9 years younger and i feel like i'm chasing something i won't catch.

I don’t really hate my major and I’m thankful I learned a bit of English which allowed me to develop myself in math, physics and coding (which I’m into) but I feel like I want more… now it seems like the way is too long, 4 years plus I want to do master and PhD so 9 years sounds terrifying

So am in front of 2 choices, 9 years to follow my goal or just doing master and doctorate in my already-have major (5 years) and accept being stuck with what i have

I know this is too long but, Please, any advice would appreciate it, a few words of wisdom, anything, really, anything would help me out.

Comment: I think it's highly unlikely that you will be able to complete a PhD in a subject you don't enjoy.

Comment: Time to do some career exploration visits.  It's sometimes called "shadowing".  When you've got a short list of jobs you think you'd enjoy, and you've got some relevant coursework under your belt, then it's time to do an internship, if necessary an unpaid one, for a few months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a software developer turned college teacher, I advise a lot of students in my Information Technology program and I like to tell my students "begin with the end in mind". If I want to go to my friend's house, do I go outside and start walking/driving and just turn left and right hoping that one day I will get to their house? Or do I ask my friend where they live, and get a map so that I know how to get there?

Why masters and PhD? Does that help you get to where you want to go? Or are those just streets and turns that you just happen to see in front of you?

Students I work with say "I want to get a job as a developer." If that's the case, I work with them to find some job postings, look at what they require, and figure out what knowledge and skills they need to get that job, and work backwards and plan out their degree or coursework.

I recommend you think about "where you want to be". It's a difficult question to answer for many people and sometimes it's worthwhile to talk to people in the field about what they like and don't like about their job and lifestyle and what they would recommend if they were you. Once you have an "end in mind", you can then work backwards and figure out a map as to how to get there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: MS and PhD are required to get a job (and in something am into) because i live in a country with a lot of graduated students but no work chances. Also I aim to gain as much of experience in this path to help me with what i like, i mean it's like migrating the job with the hobby

Comment: Sadly here the experience is not something make you pass the HR (i know it's stupid but it's Iraq too) i do code in several languages, experienced in RE and InfoSec field but it seems like .. anyway